# 3 tier architecture in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net

when i am running this code, i am getting an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at sqlconnection. Can anybody tell me what its exactly the error.

```
public class clsDalLayer
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBCS"].ToString());

    private DataSet ExecuteSql(string sqlcmd)
    {
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmd,con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(DS);
        con.Close();
        return DS;
    }
```

Comment: Something is 'Null'. Do you have the app setting "DBCS" in the app.config file for your DAL? Put a break-point in your method and check your variables for a null object. If you add the stack trace, it may be easier to point out exactly what is null in this case.

Comment: Please rephrase your title to make it meaningful (nothing to do with architecture here, right?). Your error probably relates to attempting to use a null value - most likely reutrned by the `AppSettings["DBCS"]` part. More details are needed to have a true answer.